# macOS_SDK_headers_for_macOS_10.14.pkg doesn't exist on my system

Tags: high-sierra, xcode, ruby

I am trying to install gem packages.

I am missing the `macOS_SDK_headers_for_macOS_10.14.pkg` file from `/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Packages/`. I found the link to download the `.pkg`, but I need an Apple Developer account, which costs $100 a year.

Is there anywhere on my system besides `/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Packages/` that this file can be found? If not, is there a source where I don't have to pay $100? I just want to install a gem! I did try to use the `locate` command by the way.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different :) What is the version of macOS that you are running?

Comment: 10.13.6 is my version. Sorry didn't respond.

Comment: Do you have Xcode or Command Line Tools installed? If yes, please mention the respective versions.

Comment: Yes, I have Xcode 9.4.1 and the latest command lines tools.

Comment: It would be hard to develop C programs without it (:

Comment: Have you installed Xcode from Mac App Store? You'll need to update to Xcode 10.1 (latest version installable on macOS 10.13.6) to get macOS 10.14 SDK.

Comment: No, installing now....

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95311/discussion-between-sushila-jyothi-leveque-and-nimesh-neema).

Comment: Are you planning to use the **system Ruby**? That is supposed to be a terrible idea according to the article that I am qouting in my answer.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Please consider using **Homebrew** to install **rbenv** instead of using **system Ruby**. Then configure it to your liking and get the gems you need. Please see this [Homebrew, Ruby, and Gems](https://medium.com/@jules2689/homebrew-ruby-and-gems-78d6c26b89e) article for details.

---

To install **Homebrew**, if you have not yet, or if you had trouble with it, please follow this [Install homebrew on MacOS Mojave](https://dev.to/berry_clione/install-homebrew-on-macos-mojave-4m3m)  article or find a similar for your version of **MACOS**. The important thing is to agree to **Command Line Tools License Agreement** that may popup (or stay hidden?) in the middle of the install, and may prevent you from finishing the install.

Comment: I was more trying to install the headers to install gem packages. Thanks though.

Comment: Please consider deleting your answer. All professional ruby developers use rbenv so they can manage multiple projects with different ruby/rails versions. The moderator should remove this.